# PDF reports from Google Appengine for Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pdf-generation

What is the best way to generate PDF reports from GAE Java?

No SAAS based solutions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, just to update, there is a builtin functionality from GAE to generate PDF. That solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, but there is no point now, as Google is deprecating Conversion api, which would do that. :-( 
here is more info on api
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/conversion/
and here about deprecation of it http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/a06dd822a6cee160) lists some choices, such as [PDFJet](http://pdfjet.com/os/download.html) or the [Google Docs API](http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't accept the answer as one was Python and the other SAAS. I was looking for Java based native GAE solution. But finally google has provided the PDF generation from within GAE. That solves it.